# Chat room says I don't have enough reputation to chat

Tags: support, bug, chat

I merged 2 of my accounts, and now when I try entering a chat room, it doesn't let me post anything, saying I don't have enough reputation to chat. Here's my [stackoverflow user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4861207/jessica). I tried entering the sandbox chat room, and other random ones, and they all said the same thing.

How can I chat in chat rooms?

Note: This problem is only on Stackoverflow's website. All other Stackexchange sites (ex. superuser) don't have this problem.

Comment: *saying I don't have enough reputation to vote* - not quite sure what you mean there - did you mean "chat"? Also - it appears you were posting in a chatroom on SO about 2 hours ago - are you still experiencing difficulties?

Comment: Umm.. how many accounts do you  have?

Comment: I had 2 accounts and then merged them

Comment: @JonClements I didn't post anything in that chat room. I was only able to visit it.

Comment: @Jessica I'm referring to your posts in [this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94516/discussion-between-shudhansh-shekhar-and-jessica)

Comment: I didn't post there. If you go to the question, you'll see that those are the comments from the question that got moved over

Comment: @Jessica okay - any difference if you try now?

Comment: no. It still says the same thing

Comment: Probably caching.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I expect the chat server still assumes you are logged in with the account that got merged into your current one.

As that chat account doesn't have any rep left, you lose the ability to chat.

If you had visited your associated chat account, you would have seen this:

[image]

Which shows that you have never logged in with this account.

If you click log out at the chat server, it invalidates your session there. Once you login again, the chat server picks up your current account from the global login and that is reflected in your chat user card, now showing `last seen 22m ago`.